# Awk buffer size

Tags: awk, command-line, io-redirection

I noticed this interesting set of commands today:

```
$ seq 5 > alfa.txt
$ awk '{print 6 > ARGV[1]} 1' alfa.txt
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat alfa.txt
6
6
6
6
6
```

My first question was why am I getting several `6` rather than just one, but
then I remembered you need to close each time:

```
awk '{print 6 > ARGV[1]; close(ARGV[1])} 1' alfa.txt
```

However what also puzzles me is if I am clobbering the input from the very
beginning, how am I able to still go through and read the entire file? My guess
is that Awk is actually writing to a buffer, then writing to the actual file at
the end or perhaps every time the buffer fills.

If the latter is true, what is the buffer size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on my system, it appears to be 32768 from a file, and 65536 from a
pipe:

```
$ yes | head -100000 | tee file > pipe

$ awk '{print "n" > ARGV[1]}' file

$ sed s/y/n/ pipe | awk 'BEGIN {while (getline < "-") print > ARGV[1]}' pipe

$ wc -l file pipe
 32768 file
 65536 pipe
```

Comment: That's a different situation: your question did not use an example with pipes...

Comment: @ThomasDickey I assumed it would be the same

Comment: no... with the pipe, the shell gets involved in buffer-size.  The original question did not actually use the shell's buffers.

Answer (score 1):

It's implementation-dependent, but you're seeing awk open the output file after opening its input.  The original input-file is lost, except for awk's open file-descriptor which it reads.

That's not just awk which could do this: it's common to many applications...

p.s: the buffer is your disk (size not determinable from the question).